# Subclass constructor throws TypeError: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 5 were given

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, inheritance

This is my very first day with classes and Inheritance in Python so please be gentle on me. I have two classes namely Person and Employee and where Employee is a sub class of Person.

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, place, age, sex):
        self.name = name
        self.place = place
        self.age = age
        self.sex = sex

class Employee(Person):
    def __init__(self, emp_id):
        self.emp_id = emp_id
```

Now, I am trying to create an instance of the class Employee as follows:

```
In [9]: A = Employee('Jack', 'Rome', 23, 'M')
TypeError: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 5 were given
```

What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: You overrode the `__init__` of the subclass with a function that only accepts 2 positional arguments.

Comment: do i have to over-ride the `__init__` of the subclass with all the arguments of the parent class ? I wrongly assumed that it will inherit this from the parent class..

Comment: Normally it will, but you're overwriting it on line 9.

Comment: `__init__` is passed *all* arguments given to the `ClassName(....)` call. If you inherit from another class, you need to make sure to pass on any arguments that it needs to the overridden `__init__` method. `def __init__(self, emp_id, *args, **kwargs): super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)` (newline) `self.emp_id = emp_id` would achieve that.

Comment: Related/duplicate: [Subclass - Arguments From Superclass](//stackoverflow.com/q/9840197)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python does very little "magic" in creating classes - you usually get precisely what you specified. In your case, you specified that initialising `Employee` takes only one additional argument:

```
class Employee(Person):
    # Employee initialises itself with one argument
    def __init__(self, emp_id):
        self.emp_id = emp_id
```

That means it is valid to say `Employee(1287123)`, but not `Employee('Jack', 'Rome', 23, 'M')`. For class `Employee`, `Employee.__init__` is hiding `Person.__init__`:

```
>>> Employee.__init__
<function __main__.Employee.__init__(self, emp_id)>
>>> Person.__init__
<function __main__.Person.__init__(self, name, place, age, sex)>
>>> Employee.__init__ is Person.__init__
False
```

---

If you want `Employee` to be initialised like a `Person`, you have to say so explicitly:

```
class Employee(Person):
    # Employee initialises itself like Person plus one argument
    def __init__(self, name, place, age, sex, emp_id):
        # initialise self like a Person
        Person.__init__(self, name, place, age, sex)
        # initialise self like an Employee *in addition*
        self.emp_id = emp_id
```

It is good practice not to directly invoke methods of the base class. Instead, the `super` builtin allows to dynamically invoke a method from the inheritance hierarchy:

```
class Employee(Person):
    # Employee initialises itself like Person plus one argument
    def __init__(self, name, place, age, sex, emp_id):
        # initialise self like a Person
        super().__init__(name, place, age, sex)
        # initialise self like an Employee *in addition*
        self.emp_id = emp_id
```

The purpose of `super` is to weaken the coupling of inheritance. For example, you could swap the base class `Person` for something else, and the `__init__` method would still work. See also [How does Python pass __init__ parameters with multiple inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52838240/how-does-python-pass-init-parameters-with-multiple-inheritance/52839188#52839188).

Instead of passing through arguments manually, one can use `*` and `**` to capture any unused positional and named parameters:

```
class Employee(Person):
    # Employee initialises itself with one argument
    # other positional and keyword arguments are passed to the superclass
    def __init__(self, *args, emp_id, **kwargs):
        # initialise self like the superclass
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # initialise self like an Employee *in addition*
        self.emp_id = emp_id
```

Comment: I concur..good answer but i replaced your argument repeating part with *args and **kwargs..

Answer (score 1):

You need to accept parent class arguments as well, if you're going to override `__init__` or any other method for that matter

```
class Employee(Person):
    def __init__(self, name, place, age, sex, emp_id):
        super(Employee, self).__init__(name, place, age, sex)
        self.emp_id = emp_id

>>> emp_id = '254'
>>> A = Employee('Jack', 'Rome', 23, 'M', emp_id)
```

Comment: @AndrasDeak done.

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass the extra init arguments along to the super class init method.

```
class Employee(Person):
    def __init__(self, emp_id, *args, **kwargs):
        self.emp_id = emp_id
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

By using `*args, **kwargs`, the child class will pass all uncaptured positional and named arguments to the superclass init method. This means you don't have to specify the argument names that the parent requires, or their required order. It's enough to specify that in the parent class init method.

Answer (score 0):

You defined Employee as follow:

```
class Employee(Person):
    def __init__(self, emp_id):
        self.emp_id = emp_id
```

The construictor (function `__init__()` has only 2 arguments (`self` and `emp_id`). You can create an instance passing the name, place, age and sex.

Answer (score 0):

you called the class Employee, not a Person, the person will take the 4 params and Employee will take only one param.

The created object of the class Employee, not any Person class.

```
    A = Employee(20)  # 20 is the emp_id.
```

Try with this.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass args and kwargs to accomodate multiple arguments:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, place, age, sex):
        self.name = name
        self.place = place
        self.age = age
        self.sex = sex

class Employee(Person):
    def __init__(self, emp_id, *args, **kwargs):
        Person.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.emp_id = emp_id

A = Employee(1111, 'Jack', 'Rome', 23, 'M')
```

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to update the code, its updated now