# Diamond problem - multiple inheritance python - method called just once - but how?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiple-inheritance

In this example below, the method `m` on class `A` is called just once.

I understand this is a feature, this is the Pythonic way to solve the issue where `A`'s `m` method would be called twice (if it was implemented in the naive way) in this diamond-like inheritance scenario.

This is all described here:
https://www.python-course.eu/python3_multiple_inheritance.php

(1) But under the hood... how did they achieve this behavior i.e. that class `A`'s `m` method is called ONLY once?!
Asked simplistically: which line is being "skipped" during execution - is it line `#1` or line `# 2` ?

Could someone shed more light on this?
I have never used multiple inheritance seriously because I mostly program in Java. So I am really curious about this scenario here and more specifically to the inner-workings behind it.

Note: I just want to get the general idea of how this works in Python, not really understand every tiny detail here.

(2) What if I want (in this same scenario and for some reason) `A`'s `m` method to be called twice *(or `N` times depending on how many base classes of `D` we have)*, while still going through using `super()`. Is this possible? Does `super()` support such mode of operation?

(3) Is this just some tree or [DAG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph) visiting algorithm where they keep track which class's `m` method has already been visited and just don't visit it (call it) twice? If so then *simplistically speaking* I guess '# 2' is the line which is skipped.

```
class A:
    def m(self):
        print("m of A called")

class B(A):
    def m(self):
        print("m of B called")
        super().m() # 1 

class C(A):
    def m(self):
        print("m of C called")
        super().m()  # 2 

class D(B,C):
    def m(self):
        print("m of D called")
        super().m()


if (__name__ == '__main__'):
    x = D()
    x.m()
```

Comment: To your first question, it's my understanding that `super()` checks the method resolution order of the class, which can be found by calling `help()` on an object, and simply picks the method of the next in line. If you want more details on how the MRO is calculated, I suggest reading up on C3 linearization. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C3_linearization

Comment: As a more direct answer to your question, neither #1 or #2 are skipped. `D.m()` calls `B.m()` which calls `C.m()` which calls `A.m()`.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "the method ``m`` on class A is called just once"? All of ``D.m``, ``C.m``, ``B.m`` and ``A.m`` are called; neither #1 nor #2 are skipped. What would you expect to happen if the method is called "twice"?

Comment: The brackets around the if condition are unnecessary in Python.

Comment: Can we close this question as it runs for me ok?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does Python pass ``__init__`` parameters with multiple inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52838240/how-does-python-pass-init-parameters-with-multiple-inheritance)

Comment: @Axe319 Oh... is that how it works? This simple statement you wrote clarifies a lot. Thanks for the link too about C3 linearization. That was straight to the point.

Comment: @Justlearnedit Runs OK for me too, that is why I am asking it. If one has just learnt it maybe one should be more humble :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has to do with the **Method Resolution Order**, which the article you linked already provided some insight (and more information from [this other article as well](https://realpython.com/python-super/#super-in-multiple-inheritance)):

> The question arises how the super functions makes its decision. How
>   does it decide which class has to be used? As we have already
>   mentioned, it uses the so-called method resolution order(MRO). It is
>   based on the [C3 superclass linearisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C3_linearization) algorithm. This is called a
>   linearisation, because the tree structure is broken down into a linear
>   order. The mro method can be used to create this list:
>
> ```
> >>> from super_init import A,B,C,D`  
> >>> D.mro() [<class 'super_init.D'>, <class 'super_init.B'>, <class 'super_init.C'>, <class 'super_init.A'>, <class 'object'>]`
> ```

Pay attention to the MRO where it goes from `D` > `B` > `C` > `A`.   Where you believe `super()` to be simply calling the parent class of the current scope - it is not.  It is looking through your *object*'s class MRO (i.e. `D.mro()`) with current class (i.e. `B`, `C`...) to determine which is the next class in line to resolve the method.

The [`super()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super) actually uses two arguments, but when called with zero arguments *inside a class*, it's implicitly passed:

> Also note that, aside from the zero argument form, `super()` is not
>   limited to use inside methods. The two argument form specifies the
>   arguments exactly and makes the appropriate references. The zero
>   argument form only works inside a class definition, as the compiler
>   fills in the necessary details to correctly retrieve the class being
>   defined, as well as accessing the current instance for ordinary
>   methods.

To be precise, at the point of `B.m()`, the `super()` call actually translates to:

```
super(B, x).m()
# because the self being passed at the time is instance of D, which is x
```

That call resolves within the `D.mro()` from the `B` class onward, which actually is `C`, not `A` as you imagined.  Therefore, `C.m()` is called first, and within it, the `super(C, x).m()` resolves to `A.m()` and that is called.

After that, it resolves back to after the `super()` within `C.m()`, back up to after the `super()` within `B.m()`, and back up to `D.m()`.  This is easily observed when you add a few more lines:

```
class A:
    def m(self):
        print("m of A called")

class B(A):
    def m(self):
        print("m of B called")
        print(super())
        super().m() # resolves to C.m        
        print('B.m is complete')

class C(A):
    def m(self):
        print("m of C called")
        print(super())
        super().m()  # resolves to A.m
        print('C.m is complete')

class D(B,C):
    def m(self):
        print("m of D called")  
        print(super())
        super().m() # resolves to B.m
        print('D.m is complete')

if (__name__ == '__main__'):
    x = D()
    x.m()
    print(D.mro())
```

Which results in:

> ```
> m of D called
> <super: <class 'D'>, <D object>>
> m of B called
> <super: <class 'B'>, <D object>>
> m of C called
> <super: <class 'C'>, <D object>>
> m of A called
> C.m is complete  # <-- notice how C.m is completed before B.m
> B.m is complete
> D.m is complete
> [<class '__main__.D'>, <class '__main__.B'>, <class '__main__.C'>, <class '__main__.A'>, <class 'object'>]
> ```

So in actuality, nothing is ever called twice or skipped.  You just misinterpreted the idea of the MRO resolving from the call based on the scope where `super()` is, as opposed to the call from the *initial object*.

---

Here's another fun little example to demonstrate the MRO in more details:

```
def print_cur_mro(cls, obj):
    # helper function to show current MRO
    print(f"Current MRO: {' > '.join([f'*{m.__name__}*' if m.__name__ == cls.__name__ else m.__name__ for m in type(obj).mro()])}")

class X:
    def m(self):
        print('m of X called')
        print_cur_mro(X, self)
        try:
            super().a_only() # Resolves to A.a_only if called from D(), even though A is not in X inheritance
        except AttributeError as exc:
            # Resolves to AttributeError if not called from D()
            print(type(exc), exc)
        print('X.m is complete')

class A:
    def m(self):
        print("m of A called")
        print_cur_mro(A, self)

    def a_only(self):
        print('a_only called')

class B(X):
    def m(self):
        print("m of B called")
        print_cur_mro(B, self)
        super().m() # Resolves to X.m
        print('B.m is complete')

    def b_only(self):
        print('b_only called')

class C(A):
    def m(self):
        print("m of C called")
        print_cur_mro(C, self)
        try:
            super().b_only() # Resolves to AttributeError if called, since A.b_only doesn't exist if from D()
        except AttributeError as exc:
            print(type(exc), exc)
        super().m() # Resolves to A.m
        print('C.m is complete')

    def c_only(self):
        print('c_only called, calling m of C')
        C.m(self)

class D(B,C):
    def m(self):
        print("m of D called")
        print_cur_mro(D, self)
        super().c_only() # Resolves to C.c_only, since c_only doesn't exist in B or X.
        super().m() # Resolves to B.m
        print('D.m is complete')

if (__name__ == '__main__'):
    x = D()
    x.m()
    print(D.mro())
    x2 = X()
    x2.m()
    print(X.mro())
```

Result:

> ```
> # x.m() call:
> m of D called
> Current MRO: *D* > B > X > C > A > object
> c_only called, calling m of C
> m of C called
> Current MRO: D > B > X > *C* > A > object
> <class 'AttributeError'> 'super' object has no attribute 'b_only'
> m of A called
> Current MRO: D > B > X > C > *A* > object
> C.m is complete
> m of B called
> Current MRO: D > *B* > X > C > A > object
> m of X called
> Current MRO: D > B > *X* > C > A > object
> a_only called
> X.m is complete
> B.m is complete
> D.m is complete
>
> # D.mro() call:
> [<class '__main__.D'>, <class '__main__.B'>, <class '__main__.X'>, <class '__main__.C'>, <class '__main__.A'>, <class 'object'>]
>
> # x2.m() call:
> m of X called
> Current MRO: *X* > object
> <class 'AttributeError'> 'super' object has no attribute 'a_only'
> X.m is complete
>
> # X.mro() call:
> [<class '__main__.X'>, <class 'object'>]
> ```

Comment: I am not sure I follow all this... but I will definitely re-read it a few more times at a later point. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I've updated the later sample with a current MRO to show what the `super()` resolves to, maybe it'll help with understanding what's happening.